# Easiest way to filter elements out of an XML document in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

Let's say I have the following doc

```
<sets version="2.0">
  <setting>
    <id>set1</id>
    <value>80</value>
    <label>EVersion</label>
    <type>Val</type>
    <format>R</format>
    <bits>
      <addr>0</addr>
      <startBit>0</startBit>
      <bitWidth>8</bitWidth>
    </bitspec>
  </setting>
  <setting>
    <id>set3</id>
    <value>50</value>
    <label>GVersion</label>
    <type>Bin</type>
    <format>R</format>
    <bits>
      <addr>0</addr>
      <startBit>0</startBit>
      <bitWidth>8</bitWidth>
    </bitspec>
  </setting>
  </sets>
```

and I just want the ID and value elements -

```
<sets version="2.0">
  <setting>
    <id>set1</id>
    <value>80</value>
  </setting>
  <setting>
    <id>set3</id>
    <value>50</value>
  </setting>
  </sets>
```

How could I select just these using XDocument and LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use linq-to-xml, the following code:

```
var xml_str = @"<sets version=""2.0"">
  <setting>
    <id>set1</id>
    <value>80</value>
    <label>EVersion</label>
    <type>Val</type>
    <format>R</format>
    <bits>
      <addr>0</addr>
      <startBit>0</startBit>
      <bitWidth>8</bitWidth>
    </bits>
  </setting>
  <setting>
    <id>set3</id>
    <value>50</value>
    <label>GVersion</label>
    <type>Bin</type>
    <format>R</format>
    <bits>
      <addr>0</addr>
      <startBit>0</startBit>
      <bitWidth>8</bitWidth>
    </bits>
  </setting>
  </sets>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml_str);

var settings = new XElement("sets",
    from setting in doc.Element("sets").Elements("setting")
    select new XElement("setting", setting.Element("id"), setting.Element("value")));

Console.WriteLine(settings);
```

prints:

```
<sets>
  <setting>
    <id>set1</id>
    <value>80</value>
  </setting>
  <setting>
    <id>set3</id>
    <value>50</value>
  </setting>
</sets>
```

If you don't need transformed XML, but just, say, dictionary of `id -> value` mapping, (storing `value` as `int`), you could do:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml_str);
var settings_dict = doc.Element("sets").Elements("setting").ToDictionary(s => s.Element("id").Value, s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Element("value").Value));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\myxml.xml");

var settings = 
    xdoc.Element("sets").Elements("setting")
    .Select(s => new 
       { 
         Id = s.Element("id").Value, 
         Value = s.Element("value").Value 
       });
```

This would produce an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type, with properties `Id` and `Value` (both strings).

You could create your own `Setting` type, and use that in the projection instead, also converting the 'value' string value to an integer if required.

Answer (score 0):

My first answer was very similar to the other answers, and wasn't as clear, so I removed it.  However, I thought it would be a good exercise to write some linq that would generate the filtered XML when the desired elements were at any arbitrary depth.  This is what I came up with:

```
Func<XElement, XElement> f = null; 
f = e => e.Name == "id" || e.Name == "value" ? e : //on a match, return the node
    new[] { new XElement(e.Name, e.Elements().Select(f)) } //else recurse
    .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Elements().Any()); //keeping subtrees with matches

XElement resultXmlElement = f(XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString).Root);
```