# Strip Out XML from string

Tags: c#, regex, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-rpc

I am calling some XMLRPC API and sometimes I am getting some "dirty" response. Dirty response means that along with XML is returned some other content/html like:

```
<div>Some Html maybe> Or some additional string is here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<methodResponse>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value><int>30</int></value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodResponse>
```

I need a way to throw out anything what is not XML and read only XML from string response so from response above I get only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<methodResponse>
   <params>
      <param>
         <value><int>30</int></value>
      </param>
   </params>
</methodResponse>
```

If nothing it would be helpful if someone provide code which cleans only HTML and left only XML at least. Prefer code in C#

Comment: Well-formed HTML will validate as XML, so it may be easier to strip out any elements that are not in your XML responses (i.e. `methodResponse`, `params`, etc.)

Comment: Can u show the code which gives you the `"dirty" response`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9285708/easiest-way-to-filter-elements-out-of-an-xml-document-in-net) or possibly use `XSLT` to filter the response you get back from the API with something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578602/how-to-filter-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt). `XSLT` is actually pretty powerful stuff when filtering `XML`.  I know *Visual Studios* didn't support `XSLT V.2`, but if you could use `V.2` in another editor its quiet useful.